# When does Blockevent listener being triggered during the lifecycle of the transaction(invoke)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new on Hyperledger fabric. When I was reading https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/EventHub.html#registerBlockEvent

It talks:

> registerBlockEvent(onEvent, onError)
>   Register a listener to receive all block events from all the channels that the target peer is part of. The listener's "onEvent" callback gets called on the arrival of every block.

I suppose the onEvent happens AFTER "Ordering service has made the block and send it to Peers". The "Arrival of every block" is from Peer's point of view. am I correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the transaction proposal has been successfully endorsed, and before the transaction message has been successfully broadcast to the orderer, the application should register a listener to be notified of the event when the transaction achieves finality, which is when the block containing the transaction gets added to the peer's ledger/blockchain.

technically there are 3 types of events which depend on the approch that you have you can go with one of below

1. TransactionEvent
2. BlockEvent
3. Chaincodeevent